# Arrow key navigation won't move to appended TR in TABLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this table structure that uses the arrow keys to navigate through div's in the `td` . Navigation works fine when page is loaded afresh, but when more `tr` are added to the table using Jquery `append` or `insetAfter` arrow key navigation doesn't work for the new `tr` `td` cells

You can see [my live example here](http://propagh.tk/?products)

Below is the **HTML structure for the table :**

```
<table id="product_table_body" class="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
            <tr tabindex="0" id="1">
                <td><div class="product_id cells ">1</div></td>
                <td><div class="product_name cells ">STREET</div></td>
                <td><div class="product_prices product_cost_price cells ">1.00</div></td>
                <td><div class="product_warehouse cells ">TAFO-WAREHOUSE</div></td>
                <td><div class="product_quantity cells ">2</div></td>
                <td><div class="product_prices product_retail_price cells ">4.00</div></td>
                <td><div class="product_prices product_whole_sale_price cells ">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div class="product_prices product_credit_price cells ">0.00</div></td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
    var o = {
    38: 'up',
    40: 'bottom',
    37: 'prev',
    39: 'next'
}
var $cells = $('.cells');
var colcount = $("#product_table_body > tbody").find("> tr:first > td").length;


//$(window).keydown(function (key) {    
$(document).on('keydown', '.product_table_body', function (key) {
    var direction = o[key.which];
    var $active = $('.active'), $editing = $('.editing'), i=$cells.index($active);      

    if(!$active.length && !$editing.length && direction === 'bottom')
    {
        key.preventDefault();
        $cells.first().addClass('active').focus();
    }
    else
    {
        if(direction === 'next')
        {
            $active.removeClass('active').parent('td').next('td').find($cells).first().addClass('active').focus();

        }
        else if(direction === 'prev')
        {
            //if(!$editing.length)
            $active.removeClass('active').parent('td').prev('td').find($cells).first().addClass('active').focus();
        }
        else if(direction === 'up' || direction === 'bottom')
        {
            key.preventDefault();
            var p = direction === 'up' ? (i - colcount) : (i + colcount);
            if(!$editing.length)
            {
                var activeRow = $cells.removeClass('active').eq(p).addClass('active').focus();
                var RowID = activeRow.closest('tr').attr('id');
                $('.table tbody tr#'+RowID).focus();
            }
        }
    }           
});
```

Thanks

Comment: @abhitalks new rows are appended from the `Ajax` response after inserting records into database. you might want to check it out using your firebug. thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on `$cells` in the navigation:

> ```
> i = $cells.index($active)
>
> ….find($cells)…
> ```

However, `$cells` is a static collection of all the cells that were in the table when the variable was initialized. New (appended) cells won't be found when only looking for `$cells`.

Every time you append new rows, you will need to update `$cells`.

Comment: how do i go about updating the `cells`, i've tried calling `var $cells = $('.cells');` after appending rows, but still the same issue

Comment: Depends on where you're doing that. Probably you will need to omit the `var` for not creating a new local variable, but overwriting the one from your script.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by Bergi, you need to reset `$cells`. You can try doing it in your `event` binding function like :

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#product_table_body', function (key) {
    // get all cells
    var $cells = $('.cells');
    var direction = o[key.which];
    var $active = $('.active'),$editing = $('.editing'), i=$cells.index($active);
    :
    :
    :
```

Also, note the **#** before `product_table_body` instead of **.** (period), because its and ID.